# How to get DB2 Table details using C#

Tags: c#, database, db2

How I can connect and use DB2 in the C# application?
How I can get the table names of a DB2 database?
How I can see the each column name, its datatype, size, etc of a table using C#?

Comment: For what purpose?  Are you trying to get information about the schema from DB2 system tables?  Are you trying to perhaps build a Linq to DB2 data context or some other provider?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just want to connect to a DB2 database from my C# win app. after connected, i want to see the tables in a DB. After selecting each table, i want to see the table structure like column name, its datatype, size, etc. I did for MS Access. So I am trying to do the same with DB2. Pls provide any help.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  "I want to see the table structure" isn't very specific.  Do you just need a way to use a DB2 database from within .NET code, or are you doing more than that?  IBM has a DB2 .NET data provider: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.dndp.doc/htm/frlrfIBMDataDB2.htm  There are other resources as well: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4870/Connect-to-DB2-from-Microsoft-NET

Comment: thanks for the reply. Table structure means, the details like col name, datatype, size, etc. let me see the links that you have given. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you're using DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows.  If you're using another platform, it will likely have a different catalog table.

Once you have connected to the database, you can query the information from the system catalog, specifically [`SYSCAT.COLUMNS`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html).

For example, if you have a table called `SCHEMA.TABLE`, you could get the list of all the columns using a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE TABSCHEMA='SCHEMA'
  AND TABNAME  ='TABLE'
```